# Extension of an ($\mathbb{R}$, $\boxplus$) $\mathbb{Z}$-module to a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a $\mathbb{Z}$-module M := ($\mathbb{R}$, $\boxplus$).

Is there an extension theorem I can use to make M a vector space over the reals?

I know I can extend integer scalar multiplication to the rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$-module) using the inverse of integer multiplication then extend that to the reals but is feels a lot like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Of course you can.  $\Bbb{Q}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} M, \Bbb{R}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} M$.  See [Extension of Scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).  But it kills all torsion so you may not like the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your restatement only takes care of the cardinality issue, but that is not enough. You still need that your group $M$ is isomorphic as a group to some $\mathbb{R}^n$, and your condition only ensures that it has the same cardinality.

For instance, the infinite product $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but it has torsion so it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, it cannot be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

In order for $M$ to have an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure, it must satisfy $|M|=|\mathbb{R}|$ (or $|M|\geqslant |\mathbb{R}|$ if you allow infinite dimension), *and* that $M$ is a uniquely divisible group, which means that for any $m\in M$, and any non-zero $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a unique $m'\in M$ such that $nm'=m$.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

No.  In fact, this is rarely possible.  The group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is naturally a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but it cannot possibly be a unital $\mathbb{R}$-module (i.e., $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) for cardinality reasons.  In other words, a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space *must* be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that is far from true for abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules).

For the same reason, your second paragraph is also false:  not all $\mathbb{Z}$-modules can be naturally extended to $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I restated the problem, thank you.